# List less in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to write a predicate for 2 lists `list_less(L1, L2)` that is true if the list `L1` is less than the list `L2` with respect to the ordering below:

```
list_less(L1, L2) iff  
 Let L1' := complement(L1,L2), L2' := complement(L2,L1)  
  (complement(L1,L2) contains those elements of L1  
   that are not in L2)  
 Let m1 := max(L1'), m2 := max(L2')  
  (max(L) gives the maximal element of L with respect to  
   the standard order @<)  
 m1 @< m2.
```

and the output something like this :

```
?- list_less([3,3,3,3,2,2],[3,3,4,0]).
true.

?- list_less([a,b,X,Y,[X|Y],2], [[X,X|Y]]).
true.

?- list_less([a,b,X,Y,[X|Y],2], [X,b,b]).
false.
```

I started with this :

```
list_less([],[]).
list_less([H|T],[X|Y]):-
    complement([H|T],[X|Y],L),
    max_list(H|T],M1).

complement([],[],[]). 
complement([H|T],[X|Y],L):-
    member(H,[X|Y]),
    !,
    complement(T,Y,[X|_]).

max_list(L, Max):-
    select(Max, L, Rest),
    \+ (member(E, Rest), E > Max).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more compact solution (than one that computes the difference lists first).

```
list_less(As, Bs):-
    sort(As, SortedAs),
    reverse(SortedAs, RevAs),
    sort(Bs, SortedBs),
    reverse(SortedBs, RevBs),
    RevAs @< RevBs.
```

The two lists are first sorted and reversed and then compared w.r.t. the standard order of terms. That means that elements are being compared starting from the left. Hence, the first two different elements (that correspond to the maximum element of each list that doesn't occur in the other) will make the comparison succeed or fail. This works because `sort/2` removes the duplicates also.

```
| ?- list_less([3,3,3,3,2,2],[3,3,4,0]).

(4 ms) yes
| ?- list_less([a,b,X,Y,[X|Y],2], [[X,X|Y]]).

yes
| ?- list_less([a,b,X,Y,[X|Y],2], [X,b,b]).

no
```